# Cascading dropdown not populating ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a test project built in ASP.NET Core 3.1/EF Core, created with a database-first approach.

In the `Home/Privacy` Razor view, I have 2 dropdowns which should be cascading, so the 2nd dropdown list should be populated based on the value from the first.

The example I've followed is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NnLSrRYMxo which uses an ADO connection to the database.

Currently the first dropdown populates (Area) but the 2nd (Team) doesn't.

I've reviewed the code several times to check it against the example, including against the downloaded solution and debugged whilst running the project, it looks like the Ajax code doesn't seem to be running upon the change of value in the Area dropdown.

The list for the dropdown is therefore blank.

There are NO error messages appearing when the project is running.

Code is as follows:

Stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ddl].[getAllAreas]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [ddl].[Area]
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [ddl].[getTeamsByAreaId]
    @AreaId
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [ddl].[Team]
    WHERE AreaId = @AreaId
END
```

Home controller:

```
namespace CentralMISData.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        DataAccessLayer.Ado ado = new DataAccessLayer.Ado();

        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            DataSet ds = ado.GetAllAreas();

            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["AreaName"].ToString(),
                        Value = dr["AreaId"].ToString() });
            }

            ViewBag.Arealist = list;

            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetTeamList(int areaid)
        {
            DataSet ds = ado.GetTeamByAreaId(areaid);

            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = dr["TeamName"].ToString(),
                    Value = dr["TeamId"].ToString()
                });
            }

            return Json(list);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

DataAccessLayer ADO Class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CentralMISData.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class Ado
    {
        readonly SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=CentralMISData;Integrated Security=True;");

        // Get Area List
        public DataSet GetAllAreas()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ddl.getAllAreas", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            return ds;
        }

        public DataSet GetTeamByAreaId(int areaId)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ddl.getTeamByAreaId", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaId", areaId);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Home/Privacy.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<script src="~\js\site.js"></script>
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Area</label>
                    <select id="ddlArea" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Arealist, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Team</label>
                    <select id="ddlTeam" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

site.js

```
$(function () {
    $("ddlArea").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetTeamList", { areaid: $("#ddlArea").val() }, function (d) {
            var row = "";
            $("#ddlTeam").empty();
            $.each(d, function (i, v) {
                row += "<option value=" + v.value + ">" + v.text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#ddlTeam").html(row);
        })
    })
});
```

I'm quite new to C# and Ajax etc, just trying to learn by trying different things.

I cannot myself see anything that is preventing the 2nd dropdown from being populated.

If anyone can suggest or point out where I've gone wrong then it would be very much appreciated.

Alternatively if anyone can suggest an alternative/improved/better way of creating cascading dropdowns then again it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: When debugging,what is  the vaule of list?

Comment: Does the debugger jump into "GetTeamList" when you are changing the dropdown?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.   The debugger does not jump into 'GetTeamsList'.

Comment: When checking the request in Network of devtools,what you will see?

Comment: Hi @YiyiYou, thank you for responding to my question, I have now found a way of performing this functionality.  I decided not to take the ADO route, I will post my solution as an answer to my own question.

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi @MiVoth thank you for responding to my question, I have now found a way of performing this functionality. I decided not to take the ADO route, I will post my solution as an answer to my own question. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've manabged to find a solution to the question I had by conducting further research/reading.

Here's the solution.

If anyone can improve on this solution I would be very interested to know how as I'm still at the early stages of learning asp.net/MVC

Create function in EmployeeController

```
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            List<Area> areaList = new List<Area>();

            areaList = (from area in _context.Area
                        select area).ToList();

            areaList.Insert(0, new Area { AreaId = 0, AreaName = "Select Area" });


            ViewData["GradeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Grade, "GradeId", "GradeName");
            //ViewData["AreaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Area, "AreaId", "AreaName");
            ViewBag.listOfArea = areaList;
            //ViewData["TeamId"] = new SelectList(_context.Team, "TeamId", "TeamName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Employees/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmployeeId,Pid,Fname,Lname,GradeId,AreaId,TeamId,TotalWklyHrs")] Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["AreaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Area.Where(a => a.Live == true), "AreaId", "AreaName", employee.AreaId);
            ViewData["GradeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Grade, "GradeId", "GradeName", employee.GradeId);
            ViewData["TeamId"] = new SelectList(_context.Team, "TeamId", "TeamName", employee.TeamId);
            return View(employee);
        }
```

Create View inc jQuery script

```
@model CentralMISData.Models.Db.Employee

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Employee</h4>
<hr />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#areaId').change(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Employees/GetTeamsList";
            var ddlsce = "#areaId";
            $.getJSON(url, { AreaId: $(ddlsce).val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#teamId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, team) {
                    items += "<option value='" + team.value + "'>" + team.text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#teamId').html(items);
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Pid" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Pid" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Pid" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fname" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Lname" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Lname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Lname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="GradeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="GradeId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GradeId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AreaId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="AreaId" class="form-control" id="areaId" name="areaId"
                        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfArea, "AreaId", "AreaName"))"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                
                <label class="control-label">Team</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="teamId" name="teamId" asp-for="TeamId"
                        asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "TeamId", "TeamName"))"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TotalWklyHrs" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TotalWklyHrs" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TotalWklyHrs" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Many thanks to those who replied to my question.